# want to call a service method in authguard services

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, auth-guard

I'm new to angular and I just need to call a service method in the authguard service. The service function I just need is as follows. Note: Do not want to change the service function.

```
loadOrganizations() {
    this.getOrganizations().subscribe(
      (results) => {
        const organizationList = [];
        if (results.organizations) {
          results.organizations.forEach((element) => {
            this.appendOrganization(element, organizationList);
            this.loadChildrenOrganization(element.children, organizationList);
          });
        }
        this.organizations$.next(organizationList);
        this.organizations$.complete();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.organizations$.next([]);
        this.organizations$.complete();
      }
    );
  }
```

calling method in my authguard ts is as follows.

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {
 
     this.appService.loadOrganizations().then((answer: boolean) => {
          return answer;
      });
  }
```

I got a return type error in place "Promise" and "then". any clue on how to call this service method in authguard service?

Comment: You need to convert observable to promise first in your loadorganisation function -https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise

Comment: can't we do the conversion of observable of this function to promise in the authguard function without changing the loadorganisation function

Comment: you need to return the observable and then subscribe to it in the auth guard service

Comment: `loadOrganizations()` function returns nothing neither promise nor observable. Return observable and then you can subscribe or can convert it to promise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support. I got it resolved by

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
     this.appService.loadOrganizations();
     console.log("authuard is calling")
     return true;
  }
```